# Why is it nutmeg and not megnut?

Tags: etymology

Why is it *nutmeg* and not *megnut?

Is it something to do with Latin/French influences on the English grammar?

Answer (score 2):

It is from Old French ***noiz mugue***, probably influenced by Medieval Latin ***nux maga***:

***[nutmeg](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nutmeg)*** (n.) :

> - "hard aromatic seed of the East Indies," c. 1300, from Old North French or Anglo-French *noiz mugue*, from Old French *nois muguete*, **unexplained alteration of *nois muscade*** "nut smelling like musk," from *nois* "nut" (from Latin *nux*) + Latin *muscada*, fem. of *muscat* "musky".
> - ***Probably influenced in English by Medieval Latin nux maga*** (compare unaltered Dutch *muskaatnoot*, German *muscatnuß*, Swedish *muskotnöt*).

(Etymonline)

***[Nutmeg](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/forums/viewthread/1094/#9827)*** (as reported by the OED):

> - NUT n.1 + a second element which is either Middle English *muge musk* (rare ...) or its etymon Anglo-Norman *muge*, *mugue* and Old French *mugue* musk (end of the 11th cent.; ultimately < post-classical Latin muscus MUSK n.), probably after Anglo-Norman *nois mugette* (also *nois muscade*, *nois muscate*) and Middle French *noix muguette* (14th cent.; 12th cent. in Old French as *noiz mugate*, *noiz muguete*, *noiz muscade*, *noiz muscate*, ...).
> - **No compound in mugue musk, directly paralleling the English word, is attested in either Anglo-Norman or Old French,** but compare post-classical Latin *nux muga* (1325), *nux de muga* (1314; both in British sources). 
>     Compare Catalan *nou moscada* ..., Old Occitan *noz muscada* (c1250), Italian *noce moscata* ..., Spanish *nuez moscada* ..., post-classical Latin *nux muscata* (see NUX MOSCHATA n.).
> - ***The Romance compound has been borrowed into several Germanic languages,***  compare Middle Dutch *notemusscate* (Dutch *nootmuskaat*, *notemuskaat*; also *muskaatnoot* denoting the fruit containing the nutmeg), Middle High German *muscātnuz* (German *Muskatnuss*), Swedish *muskotnöt*, Danish *muskatnød*. ...]

(www.wordorigins.org)

Comment: But what is it about the Latin grammar that makes it different from the German?

Comment: And any idea why we picked the Latin and not the German word?

Comment: Maga is  an adjective in that case and it usually comes after the noun, so you have the French noix muscade, the Italian noce moscata, nuez moscada in Spanish...

Comment: Probably because of the strong influence of French at that time, and of Latin as a consequence.

Comment: Probably the French influence. My impression is that a lot of cooking terms in English came directly from French. For example, *saffron, cinnamon, cardamom, sage, rosemary, thyme, clove, anice, mace, mustard* are all derived from French. While *pepper, salt, parsley, ginger, cumin, garlic* were present in Old English.

Comment: @E_L Latin has free word order, but most ordinarily it has the noun before the adjective. You see the same thing in scientific names of species. As for _why_ Latin puts the noun before the adjective, that might be a good question for http://latin.stackexchange.com or http://linguistics.stackexchange.com.